# How ro read files from multiple locations using wso2 vfs transport?

Tags: vfs, wso2-esb

> This is my proxy service developed using wso2

service..

```
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///home/user/test/in</parameter> <!--CHANGE-->
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///home/user/test/original</parameter> <!--CHANGE-->
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///home/user/test/original</parameter> <!--CHANGE-->
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <target>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="soap12" uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
        </endpoint>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
                      expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.xml')"
                      scope="transport"/>
            <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="vfs:file:///home/user/test/out"/> <!--CHANGE-->
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

> using the fileURI parameter I can read the files from a particular(file:///home/user/test/in) location and place them in another location(file:///home/user/test/out),
>   now my requirement is, I want to read the files from multiple locations and place them in a single folder, how I do this using wso2 vfs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think one VFS proxy can listen to multiple source location (transport.vfs.FileURI). You can have multiple VFS proxies to listen on multiple source location (one VFS proxy per source location) and write to the same destination location.

Comment: So i have to develop multiple proxies(multiple artifacts) for each location. Can i develop multiple VFS proxies in a single application.?

Comment: Yes - you have develop multiple VFS proxies (each listen on one source location). What you mean by single application?

Comment: it means the proxy-services(artifacts),I have developed one proxy-service with the same code as shown in the xml above, I am building this service and deploying this wso2(carbon) server.my requirement is with in one proxy-service(artifact) I have to develop multiple VFS proxies,so the end of the day I will be deploying only one service(artifact) in the wso2(carbon) server.

Comment: I want exactly inverse of recipient list endpoints ,I mean in one service I want to get the data from multiple end points and route it to one single endpoint.